# Does IE9 Not support Linear Gradients? (MVC 4 App with Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, cross-browser

I'm working on an MVC 4 Application using Bootstrap. As usual, everything works fine in Chrome, but Firefox and IE are having issues.

**Below Div is my Chrome Output**:
[image: DivInChrome]

**And here is my Div IE Output**:
[image]

**The `div` markup is**:

```
<div class="row" id="becomeMember">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <p class="largeFontSize">
            Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.ActionLink("Become a Member", "Information", "Members", new {}, new {@class = "btn btn-warning btn-lg largeFontSize"})
        <br />
        <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Become a Sponsor", "Information", "Sponsors", new {}, new {@class = "btn btn-warning btn-lg largeFontSize"})
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Color Styling**:

```
#becomeMember
{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#28435e, #3d688e); /* For Safari */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#28435e, #3d688e); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#28435e, #3d688e); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(#28435e, #3d688e); /* Standard syntax */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#28435e', endColorstr='#3d688e',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

This is my first go at MVC 4 development, let alone Twitter Bootstrap. Anyone have ideas on how I might resolve this inconsitency? I had read that I needed to add the explicit `filter` for IE 6 - 9 for the gradients, but that did not change anything.

Comment: Have a look at caniuse.com: http://caniuse.com/#search=gradient

Comment: @BillyMoat, Thanks for the link! Do yo know of any workarounds?

Comment: Scroll down a bit on this page and try the IE Filter that he suggests for IE 8-9: http://css-tricks.com/css3-gradients/

Comment: @BillyMoat, That's what I'm not getting? In my research I had found about using hte IE `Filter`, but even though I have it included in my ID as shown above, I'm still not getting the desired output in IE9?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what to suggest then I'm afraid. Personally I'm happy with graceful degradation in IE so that if the CSS gradient doesn't work then you just get a solid background colour in old versions of IE and decent browsers give the full experience.

Comment: Alright, thanks for trying in any case! I'll keep digging around and see if I can't figure out the issue. I tried setting a solid `background-color` attribute as my starting color, but I'm still getting white text on white background for the text.

Comment: Look at the way Bootstrap set the gradient on v2.3.2 and see if that helps: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/base-css.html#buttons